# Create a database and tables in runtime in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Is it possible to create a database and tables in runtime, in a Rails app?

**For example:** the server receives a request with some data. Then, it should create a database in PostgreSQL, and create also some tables in that new DB. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Sequel gem (http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) it is possible to create databases in runtime, running an SQL script.

I've tried it only with a PostgreSQL database, not sure if it is possible with others.

**For a PostgreSQL database**

***Connect to the PostgreSQL server***

To connect to the PostgreSQL server you always have to define a database to connect to. Use the 'postgres' database, a default database created by the PostgreSQL server (more info: [Default database named postgres on Postgresql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370525/default-database-named-postgres-on-postgresql-server)).

```
db = Sequel.postgres('postgres', user, password, host, port)
```

***Run the SQL script to create a database***

```
db.run "CREATE DATABASE my_new_db"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible.  Perhaps not recommended.

Comment: can you provide more information about why it is not recommended?