# database "public" does not exist - postgres/sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect postgres database from sequelize (node.js).But `sequelize` throws error like `ERROR: database "public" does not exist`.

The database url is given below:

postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/public

The show db result is given below:
[image]

I have modified the database url as follows:
`postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/postgres`, where postgres is valid database.Please find the attached image below:

[image]

Comment: database and schema in postgresql are not the same object  .. you should provide the database name not the schema name

Comment: A **database** and **schema** are two different things. You _connect_ to a database which in turn contains many schemas in which you create tables (and other objects). So, to create a table you provide a _schema_ name. So you should use `create table public.sequalizemeta ...`

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

database and schema in postgresql are not the same object .. you should provide the database name not the schema name

you could get the list of the database using

```
psql -U pgadmin -l
```

Answer (score 0):

> The postgres database is a default database meant for use by users, utilities and third party applications.

If you don't specify a database while connecting to postgres (using, day, psql), it will connect to `postgres` DB.

It is possible that you connected to postgres without specifying the DB and created the tables. Hence they were created in `postgres` DB.

References:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-initdb.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411860/12242023