# EF Core. DbContext uses wrong database

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have declared my own DbContext:

```
public class DbContextMain: DbContext
{
   // some DbSets here 

   public DbContextMain(): base()
   {        
   }

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=myip;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=test");
   }
}
```

Please note, that is being configured to use **Database=test**

But when I run the following code inside another console project:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    DbContextMain dbContextMain = new();
    dbContextMain.Database.Migrate();
}
```

I get strange exception:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: "3D000: database "postgres" does not exist"

Please note, that database mentioned in exception is "postgres" while my database is "test" (and I double checked - method OnConfiguring is executed before Migrate call)

What I do wrong?

Comment: isn't that `postgres` supposed to exists on every postgresql installation?

Comment: You are right! I created empty database "postgres" and now my code works as expected. But why do I need **postgres** database at all?

Comment: errr.. i think its better to reinstall your postgres, just to be on the safe side. i forgot what was that database used, but i remember consider it as important - maybe something like mysql's `information_schema` or something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370525/default-database-named-postgres-on-postgresql-server